# show data of the specific user who logged in

Tags: angularjs, meteor, meteor-accounts

Hello I am using `meteor` with `angular` and I am a beginner,

I've created a real-estate site where admins can add the property to be rented or sold. and those properties will show up in a client site.

I have used `meteor add accounts-ui accounts-password` and `blaze`.

I don't want to show the data of admin (a) to admin (b), the code I am using shows  the admin data to all the admin users

Code

```
Parties = new Mongo.Collection("parties");

Parties.allow({
  insert: function (userId, party) {
    return userId && party.owner === userId;
  },
  update: function (userId, party, fields, modifier) {
    return userId && party.owner === userId;
  },
  remove: function (userId, party) {
    return userId && party.owner === userId;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove the packages `insecure` and `autopublish` packages if you have not already done so.
2. Use [Meteor.publish()](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_publish) on the server to retrict both which documents are published to a user as well as which fields.
3. User [Meteor.subscribe()](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_subscribe) to subscribe to the collection(s) you publish from the server

For example, on the server:

```
Meteor.publish('myParties',function(){
  return Parties.find({ owner: this.userId() }); // return all the keys from my parties
});
Meteor.publish('otherParties',function(){
  // omit the details key from other users' parties
  return Parties.find({ owner: { $ne: this.userId() }},{ fields: { details: 0 }}); 
});
```

On the client:

```
Meteor.subscribe('myParties');
Meteor.subscribe('otherParties');
```

The allow/deny rules you show only deal with *changes* to data, not what is visible to which user.

Comment: I tried that, now i am not able to insert anything in the database!

Comment: Try just returning `true` from your *allow* rule to make sure it's not the problem. Also make sure you don't have a *deny* rule blocking you.

Comment: Can  i have your mail id sir, so that i can mail u my code, m really stuck up here!

Comment: Just heading to sleep now. Can you make a [meteorpad](http://meteorpad.com/) with your code? I can look at that tomorrow.

Comment: i will just mail you my code, that would be easier.

Comment: back online now, if you had more reputation points we could chat. Not a fan of posting my email address anywhere though. You could point me to a pastebin or something.